# how to set the active window to an opencv image using C++ opencv highgui in OSX

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, opencv, macos-carbon

In C++, how do I force an opencv window (eg after an imshow call) to the foreground?

Looking around on the net, it seems you have to get the handle, and then make some native call:

```
  imshow("img", img);
  void* handle = cvGetWindowHandle("img");
  ??
```

Then somehow use the native handle. I'm using OSX and I'm not familiar with the Carbon or Cocoa API and I'm not sure how it would interface with openCV. Can anyone provide an example of how I do this?

Also, is there an opencv 2.0 c++ alternative to cvGetWindowHandle()?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with OpenCVs highgui, but when I'm working on OSX projects I usually displaying my OpenCV output through a NSImageView. To convert my cv::Mat to a NSImage I use this helper: https://gist.github.com/1716068

Maybe it's helpful :)